# How can I pass a specific list variable to a Get and Set function?

Tags: robotframework

### How can I pass on a specific global list variable to the following Get and Set functions?

Assume there is a @{Files} list with multiple xxxx.txt files.
Assume @{Files}[0] has dinosaur.txt

```
Get the File Version 
[Arguments] @{Files}[??]    # Not sure about this
Run Keyword If  File is present 
... ${time} = OperatingSystem.Get Modified Time @{Files}[]
... ${dateonly} = Split String ${time}  ${SPACE}
... ${Version} = @{dateonly}[0]
ELSE
... ${Version} = MISSING
[Return]  ${Version}

Set a dinosaur file version test case
  ${Version} = Get the File Version @{Files}[0] # Is this right ???
  Set test variable ${Version}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List variables have two ways to use. When referenced as `${mylist}` we are referencing the underneath Python object (a variable of type List). When we use `@{mylist}` we are expanding all the elements from that list.

The following code is a fully working example reproducing your original code (you only need to create a file named `dinosaur.txt`):

```
*** Settings ***
Library         OperatingSystem
Library         Collections
Library         String

*** Test Cases ***
Test Files Versions
  @{Files}=  Create List  dinosaur.txt  bird.txt  dog.txt  cat.txt
  ${Version}=  Get the File Version  ${Files[0]}
  Log  Version of file, ${Files[0]} is ${Version}
  FOR  ${file}  IN  @{Files}
    ${file_version}=  Get the File Version  ${file}
    Log  Version of file, ${file} is ${file_version}
  END
  Set Test Variable  ${Files}
  Set a dinosaur file version test case
  Log  Version of file, ${Files[0]} is ${Version}

*** Keywords ***
Get the File Version
  [Arguments]  ${File}
  ${file_is_present}=  File is present  ${File}
  IF  ${file_is_present}
      ${time}=  OperatingSystem.Get Modified Time  ${File}
      @{dateonly}=  Split String  ${time}  ${SPACE}
      ${Version}=  Set Variable  ${dateonly[0]}
  ELSE
      ${Version}=  Set Variable If  not ${file_is_present}  MISSING
  END
  [Return]  ${Version}

Set a dinosaur file version test case
  ${Version}=  Get the File Version  ${Files[0]}
  Set test variable  ${Version}

File is present
  [Arguments]  ${File}
  ${result}=  Run Keyword And Return Status  File Should Exist  ${File}
  Return From Keyword  ${result}
```